# Why is position: relative; not working on firefox?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am postioning a div inside a relative container absolutely, but in firefox it completly ignores it.

Here is a fidde for this: http://jsfiddle.net/TThUZ/

My HTML:

```html
<div class="main">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a>
                Text
            </a>
            <div class="sub">
                Sub
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
ul { display: table; }
li { display: table-cell; width: 300px; background: #ddd; padding-left: 50px; position: relative; }
.sub { position: absolute;  left: 0; }
```

The `.sub` does not follow the position: relative of the `li`. Why? And How to fix it?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this. Are you expecting `<div class="sub">` to move to the top of the li or something? If so you're missing `top:0;` for `.sub`

Comment: Do you need the `left: 0;` in your `.sub`? I haven't tested, but I think if you remove it both should look the same.

Comment: @GrahamWalters, I goes beyond the li. That is not the expected behavior for position: relative in the parent.

Comment: Yes, I need `left:0` to bring the container aligned with the `a` in IE and chrome.

Answer (score 7):

`.sub` is doing what it is supposed to.  I believe it has to to with your `display: table-cell;`.  Check this link out for verification: http://css-tricks.com/absolutely-position-element-within-a-table-cell/

> [...]Table cell elements just won't take those position values. And
>   thus, you also can't absolutely position elements within the context
>   of those elements either.[...]

The article above suggests the following fix, add and element inside the table-cell to use positioning.  Not very semantic, but it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/TThUZ/6/

Notice the additional `div` that is using the relative positioning instead of your `li` that has `display: table-cell;`.

*HTML*

```html
<div class="main">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="table-cell-fix">
                <a>
                    Text
                </a>
                <div class="sub">
                    Sub
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now just a little extra CSS.  Move `position: relative;` from the `li` to the new `div`.  I also moved the padding you had on your `li` to the new `div`.

*CSS*

```css
ul {
    display: table;
}
li {
    display: table-cell; 
    width: 300px; 
    background: #ddd; 
}
.sub { 
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; 
    top: 0;
}
.table-cell-fix {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: It's your `display: table-cell;` that causing the issue.  Please follow the link.

Comment: The link shows issues with a HTML implementations of table, not CSS. Am i incorrect?

Comment: No, it plainly states in the intro of the article that: `Table cell elements just won't take those position values. And thus, you also can't absolutely position elements within the context of those elements either.`  The article goes on to explain some solutions.  One of which is to add and element inside the table-cell and add the positioning to that.  Please see this updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TThUZ/6/

Answer (score 0):

try setting `LI`'s display to `block` instead of `table-cell`

```
li { 
    display: block; 
}
```

I have updated your [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JudeDuran/TThUZ/2/).

Comment: I need this to work with table-cell because using it I can evenly distribute li among the ul container.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're applying styles that contradict themselves in the box model, so you wind up with what amounts to unpredictable behavior. From what I can tell, you're triggering this by specifying `display: table;` on the `<ul>`:

> The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group,
>   table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group,
>   table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.
>   (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position)

There is a table that tries to define the recommended user-agent behavior, at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo, but I couldn't quite work out which is applicable for your example.

If I removed the table rules from your CSS, the absolutely-position element *does* seem to position itself correctly in relation to the `<li>` that wraps it.

**EDIT:**

The simplest solution I came up with is to wrap the contents of each `<li>` with a `<div>`, to which you then apply a `position: relative;` rule (** denotes additions): http://jsfiddle.net/TThUZ/4/

```
<div class="main">
    <ul>
        <li>
            **<div class="test">**
                <a>
                    Text
                </a>
                <div class="sub">
                    Sub
                </div>
            **</div>**
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and

```
ul { display: table; }
li { display: table-cell; width: 300px; background: #ddd; padding-left: 50px; }
**.test { position: relative; }**
.sub { position: absolute;  left: 0; }
```

I'm fairly certain you can remove the positioning rule from the `<li>`, as it has no effect when the elements are displayed as table cells.

Comment: I know it does. But the main reason for me to use table in first place was to evenly distribute LIs among the UL

Comment: Understood, but that may not work with what you have. See my edit.